# Solr Adding PDF via ExtractRequestHandler

Tags: solr

I am trying to use the Solr handler to add a PDF document to the index but keep getting a missing Unique field error (even though I am providing the field).  Here is the request:

```
D:\Downloads\solr-4.6.0\solr-4.6.0\example\exampledocs>c:\temp\curl "http://loca
lhost:8983/solr/update/extract?commit=true&literal.MessageID=2b071dce-d7a6-4b7c-
9a09-33cc93f96db9" -F "myfile=@Wizards vs Warriors tickets.pdf"
```

The error I get back is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">135</in
t></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Document is missing mandatory uniqueKe
y field: MessageID</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

In my REST call I am using `literal.MessageID=...` but it still seems to not find it.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this? (NOTE: I did find an article on SO about problems with fields ending in `ID` so I removed the ID from the field in the schema and modified the `literal.Message` but still same issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your schema.xml

Comment: <field name="MessageID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

Comment: <uniqueKey>MessageID</uniqueKey>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your test case and found the same result. Then I did several test cases and found that the required **unique key** field name should be always in **lowercase**. That's why when you try with `MessageID`, it doesn't work.

Try with **messageid**. It'll work.

Comment: That worked.  Now to modify the 600K documents I already have with it as MessageID :(  Thanks again.